# How to show rows of zero with table

Tags: r, rows

I'm having a problem with command "table". I'm comparing two matrixs which elements are 0 or 1. I want the coincidences and no-coincidences in 0 or 1, so I wrote:

```
> asd=table(prob1,prob_obs_mod1)
> asd
     prob_obs_mod1
prob1      0      1
    0 650620 289511
```

The problem is that it doesn't show the row for 1 in prob1, because it is zero. I mean, I want "table" to show me:

```
    prob_obs_mod1
prob1      0      1
    0 650620 289511
    1      0      0
```

How can I specify that I want to have all rows, even the zero ones?

Comment: Try `table(factor(prob1,levels=0:1),factor(prob_obs_mod1,levels=0:1))`

Comment: @RHertel Posted as answer. I already generated some sample data in my attempts in a slightly (but equivalent) different  way than the one you suggested. Thank you.

Comment: thanks you! It worked very well.

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to assign `levels` to your vectors, so the occurrences of each level is counted. Try this:

```
#simulate some data
set.seed(1)
prob1<-rep(0,940131)
prob_obs_mod1<-sample(0:1,length(prob1),T)
#no row corresponding to 1
table(prob1,prob_obs_mod1)
#     prob_obs_mod1
#prob1      0      1
#    0 469799 470332
#Here it appears
table(factor(prob1,levels=0:1),factor(prob_obs_mod1,levels=0:1), dnn=c("prob1","prob_obs_mod1"))
#     prob_obs_mod1
#prob1      0      1
#    0 469799 470332
#    1      0      0
```